# Why are my stars drawing twice as large as they should on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, oop, canvas, ecmascript-6

As the final part of my flag, I need to loop a star 50 times for my USA flag to save me the hassle of creating new 50 new stars. Iv'e worked out how to create 50 stars in a loop, the only problem is, they all come out twice as big as the other. Can anyone spot the problem in my code?

```
  class Star extends drawable{
  constructor(x = 0,y = 0, outerRadius = 0, innerRadius = 0, numberOfPoints = 0, lineWidth = 0,fillStyle = "#000",strokeStyle = "transparent",context){
    super(context,x,y,fillStyle,strokeStyle,lineWidth);
    this.outerRadius = outerRadius;
    this.innerRadius = innerRadius;
    this.numberOfPoints = numberOfPoints;
}
loopDraw(){
    super.draw();
    this.context.beginPath(); 
    this.numberOfPoints = this.numberOfPoints * 2; //
    let pointOffSetRadians = (2 * Math.PI) / this.numberOfPoints; //
    for(var p = 0; p < 4; p++){
        this.context.moveTo((this.x + 40) * p,this.y - this.outerRadius); 
        for(let i = 0; i < this.numberOfPoints; i++){
            let radX,radY;
            if(i % 2 === 0){
                radX = this.outerRadius * Math.sin(i * pointOffSetRadians);
                radY = this.outerRadius * Math.cos(i * pointOffSetRadians) * -1;
            } else {
                radX = this.innerRadius * Math.sin(i * pointOffSetRadians);
                radY = this.innerRadius * Math.cos(i * pointOffSetRadians) * -1; 
            }   
                this.context.lineTo((radX + this.x + 40)*p, radY + this.y);         
        }
    }

    this.context.closePath(); 
    this.context.stroke(); 
    this.context.fill(); 
    super.afterDraw();  
}
}
const star1 = new Star(24,130,18,7,5,0,"white","green",context4);
star1.loopDraw();
```

Comment: think I found it. You set star1.numberOfPoints to a certain value. After that, you multiply it by two each time you pass your loop. Am I right or did I get the idea wrong?

Comment: @Evochrome If that's the case, then what would you suggest that I change it to? because Iv'e tried setting it to * p and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well, shouldn't the number of points be the same for every star? So, multiply it by two inside the `Star` class instead of the `loopDraw` class

Comment: @Evochrome Okay just tried this and it made no difference at all, I think it's a problem in the loopDraw class, I just can't figure out what.